# How to synchronize with NSUserDefaults in Settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

I created my application settings in `Settings.bundle`. I go into the `Settings App` and update a value. When I relaunch my app (which was in the background), how do I check for the updated settings in the `Settings App`.

I tried the following but I still get the old value. Any suggestions?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkAutoUpdateSettingsForNotificaiton:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

- (void)checkAutoUpdateSettingsForNotificaiton:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSNumber *period = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"periodID"] retain];

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` to do the synchronization.